# Hatcher exercise 1.2.13

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, klein-bottle

In this exercise we consider a disk with two holes and we identify the three boundary circles. There are only two essentially different ways of identifying the three boundary circles: one gives a modified Klein bottle, say $Y$, and the other gives another topological space $Z$. I have to show that their fundamental groups are different (i.e $\pi_1(Y)$ is not isomorphic to $\pi_1(Z)$). My problem is: I have no idea how to compute these fundamental groups. Any suggestion of method ?

Comment: Have you tried using van Kampen's theorem?

Comment: try to figure out the polygonal representation.

Comment: @CliveNewstead I wanted to use it but I don't know with which open cover

Comment: @Anubhav I don't know what is the polygonal representation

Comment: It is there in the 1st chapter of Hatcher.